# Truffle error "Don't set config.from directly"

Tags: truffle

I have parity running on my mac and I can start it with

```
parity --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8547 --port 30305 --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcapi "eth,net,web3"
```

Once It's all sync'd up I then make a new directory and `cd` into it and then `truffle init` I then change truffle.js

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "0.0.0.0",
      port: 8547,
      network_id: "1" 
    }
  }
};
```

I run `truffle test` and get

```
Error: Don't set config.from directly. Instead, set config.networks and 
then config.networks[<network name>].from
    at Config.set [as from] 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:1868:15)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:209751:21
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

and if i try to deploy a test contract

```
truffle migrate --reset
Using network 'development'.

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23538
    throw new Error("Expected parameter '" + key + "' not passed to 
function.");
    ^

Error: Expected parameter 'from' not passed to function.
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23538:15
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.options 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:23536:19)
at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:72807:12)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:95270:23
at Object.needsMigrating (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:72955:14)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:95266:19
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:58698:9
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:37442:13
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:220423:9
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I restarted my computer to fix this issue. As there are a few StackOverflow questions on this topic and no answers, they may be related to a local-state issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue with Pantheon client (it doesn’t support account management at the moment).

Make sure that your node returns at least one imported account in response for `eth_accounts` call (more information here https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_accounts):

`curl --data '{"method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545`

It should return a response like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":["0x254fccb0603859f096be3151b10ec4337b4fec57"],"id":1}
```

But if you see an empty array inside `result` filed instead, this means that you should check `Account Options` section in your Parity config. Probably you forgot to import or specify account(s) to use.