# Why does truffle always fail with "Error: Don't set config.from directly. Instead, set config.networks and then config.networks[<network name>].from"

Tags: contract-development, truffle, testing, truffle-migration

I have a problem that suddenly appeared, and now I get it every time that I try to run `truffle test` or `truffle migrate`, regardless of which project it is. I've even tried fetching the Petshop from the truffle docs (http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop), and I still get the same error:

```
   mybox@c:~/code/petshop (master)$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.

Error: Don't set config.from directly. Instead, set config.networks and then config.networks[<network name>].from
    at Config.set [as from] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:3019:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:320066:21
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

It seems like it protests that I'm using the old syntax for setting `from`, wanting me to do it for each network. However, this is done in the `truffle.js` file of all of the projects. It almost seems as there is some kind of global config that overrides the local somewhere, but I have no idea where.

I've tried reinstalling and downgrading truffle, to no avail.

Versions:

- Node v9.4.0
- Truffle 4.0.1

Comment: I've seen this same error using parity as the client - and this is confirmed by https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28998/truffle-error-dont-set-config-from-directly. I have no solution (other than using testrpc). Are you using parity?

Comment: I wasn't aware that parity was running - however, `ps aux | grep parity` told me otherwise. Stopping parity magically makes the tests run again, for some reason. Can you please post your comment as an answer so that I can award the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this same error using parity as the client - and this is confirmed by [Truffle error "Don't set config.from directly"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28998/)….

I have no solution though, other than using testrpc

Answer (score 1):

Met the same issue and solved it with following steps in geth:
1, eth.accounts replies null

2, personal.newAccount()

3, personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be either your error comes from the your migrations/deploy scripts, either it comes from your truffle-config file.

Could you provide some code of those in order we can get more into details ?